# I want to show in google sheets the summary of quiz results

Tags: google-sheets

I have quizes being sent out every week and the results are being sent to a goodle sheet and I want to create a tab that is a summary.
I want a formula that can look up an email address in another sheet (found in column B) and if the email address is there, to show the result of the quiz for that email address (found in column C).
Is there a way to do that?

The closest that I could get is something like this:

```
=IF(MATCH("email@address.com",'Form Responses 1'!B:B,0),'Form Responses 1'!C:C, "Not Submitted")
```

But that doesn't show anything if the email address exists

Comment: Welcome! It seems to me that you are looking for something similar to `=IFERROR(INDEX('Form Responses 1'!C:C,MATCH("email@address.com",'Form Responses 1'!B:B,0)),"Not Submitted")`. Look on this resource, a lot has been written about the `INDEX(...,MATCH(...))` combination.

Answer (score -1):

This problem is simple and formatted perfectly to the vlookup function:

```
=lambda(fox,den,iferror(Vlookup(fox,den,2,n(whatthefoxsay())),"Not Submitted"))("email@address.com",'Form Responses 1'!B:C)
```